# Edit INI to replace string with batch

Tags: batch-file

Im needing to edit an ini file to replace a line inside with a new destination folder.

I need it to go to a new path.  I've tried a few similar searches but have been unable to get it to work on my own.  Here's one I tried and nothing happened:

```
@echo off
set "file=C:\Users\Test\AppData\Roaming\OBS\profiles\Test.ini"
if exist "%file% (
   findstr /v /i "SavePath=" "%file%" >"%file%.tmp"
   >>"%file%.tmp" echo/SavePath=C:\test\backup\backup.flv
   move /y "%file%.tmp" "%file%" >nul
)
```

Comment: You are writing out SavePath to the temp file with the old and new. What is your expected end result? Are there more lines in the INI file then just this one line that you need to keep?

Comment: Yes I need to keep the rest of the ini file in tact, I just need to change the data in this line to a new path.  There are 2 other items i need to change but this was the major one.  Also I will note I can't add any other programs/batch like jrepl to the systems.

Comment: Perhaps it should read - `if exist "%file%"` note the closing doublequote! Also it may be worth mentioning that were you to change that line to read `If Not Exist "%file%" Exit /B` you wouldn't need to have that multiline `If` block. As a final note, you can replace `C:\Users\Test\AppData\Roaming` with `%AppData%`.

Comment: Thanks for the " i missed that, so I can get it to remove/rewrite, but it adds it  at the end instead of where it was, any ideas on that?

Comment: You should process each line one by one; perhaps from a `For` loop which checks each line and outputs either it's direct or modified content as necessary. There are hundreds of examples  of this kind of structure on this site alone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an exerpt from a batch file I use daily for some templating.  It will replace the specified `search` string with a new `replace` string as defined at the top of the file:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "search=c:\old\path"
set "replace=d:\new\path"
set "textfile=test.ini"
set "newfile=output.ini"
echo Scanning %textfile%

(for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr "." "%textfile%"') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>"%newfile%"
```

It looks like you are already handling `if exist` and overwriting the original file so I have not included those pieces.

Hope it helps!